# How to create MD5 file using GNU Makefile?

Tags: gnu-make, md5, gnu

I have this Makefile which converts pnm file to png file. pnm file is in the `inputs` directory and then converted file (png) should be in the `outputs` directory. My question is how I need to create this summary MD5 file that sums my png file in the `outputs` using GNU make? I tried writing this rule, but it still doesn't create any MD5 file, only outputs the png file.

```
$(MD5_FILE): $(OUTPUT_FILES)
    md5 $@ $^
```

This is my Makefile code

```
INPUT_DIR = inputs
OUTPUT_DIR = outputs

INPUT_FILES = $(wildcard $(INPUT_DIR)/*.pnm)
OUTPUT_FILES = $(INPUT_FILES:$(INPUT_DIR)/%.pnm=$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.png)
MD5_file = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/md5-file.md5

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUT_FILES) $(MD5_FILE)

$(MD5_FILE): $(OUTPUT_FILES)
    md5 $@ $^

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.png: $(INPUT_DIR)/%.pnm
    pnmtopng $<  > $@ 

.PHONY: clean distclean
clean: 
    rm -f $(OUTPUT_FILES)
distclean: clean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify an output file; you are asking it to print the MD5 for the previous (nonexistent, empty, or stale) output file as well as the input files.

```
$(MD5_FILE): $(OUTPUT_FILES)
    md5 $^ >$@
```

You'll also want to make sure you specify the variable consistently; here, you are calling it `MD5_FILE` whereas above in the assignment you used `MD5_file`.

Finally, you'll also want to remove this file in the `clean` target.

Comment: The command name `md5` suggests that you are on BSD or a Mac. If you are on a different platform, you might have a utility with the same name but different semantics for the file name arguments, in which case please edit your question to clarify which platform you're on, and, ideally, whether portability is important to you.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22 platform right now.

Comment: On Linux the command is usually `md5sum`, not `md5`.